# Clean up intentionally deleted Virtualbox drives manually

Tags: virtualbox

I deleted two virtual disks from a VirtualBox VM the wrong way. I removed them from the guest config, but forgot to remove them from the media list, and deleted the files and directories from the filesystem, so I see the disks as errored in the media list. They have associated snapshots, so I get errors about them being in use. If I try to delete the associated snapshots via the GUI or `vboxmanage` I get this error message:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: VD: error VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND opening image file [location]
```

Of course the snapshots are also gone (these were old vmdk files I mounted, so the snapshots may not even be real). How do I manually remove these ghost entries from my VirtualBox config? I suspect there's a config file or a registry entry, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: VirtualBox doesn’t use the Windows registry in this capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the first response, which did not work, I found the solution. The solution is to stop VirtualBox, then go into the directory for the (or each) individual VMs that reference the disk images in question, edit the .vbox file for the VM, delete the HardDisk entries (including snapshots), and then start up VirtualBox again. The media manager will show no entries for those disks.

Answer (score 5):

Hope this helps somebody.

`cat ~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml | grep your_roguedisk.vdi`

Grab the output of the UUID.

`$ vboxmanage closemedium disk "{d89ef84a-d754-4da2-b2a1-cc37063d0c6d}" --delete`

Answer (score 1):

The error is like the following screenshot:

[image: VirtualBox_File_Not_Found_Error]

`VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` means the provided file path is not valid. After any operation
with VBoxManage, VirtualBox saves the file path in Global Configuration file.
The file is a XML format file. VirtualBox maintains global configuration data
in the following directory:

- Linux and Oracle Solaris: `$HOME/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml`
- Windows: `%UserProfile%\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml` or `C:\Users\UserName\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml`
- Mac OS X: `$HOME/Library/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml`

That file contains configuration of every Virtual Machines. So *back it up* before edit.
Open that `VirtualBox.xml` file in any text editor. Find the file path that you
want to delete. Generally the path resides in `<HardDisk/>` tag.
For example, the format will be like this:

```xml
<HardDisks>
    <HardDisk uuid="{3761d018-e224-45d4-aa61-764d2c408712}" location="F:/test.VHD" format="VHD" type="Normal"/>
    <HardDisk uuid="{9f4f1f1c-f4c9-4773-a0b3-f0c52f699142}" location="F:/test.VMDK" format="vmdk" type="Normal"/>
</HardDisks>
```

Remove the full tag line otherwise VBox shows error. That's why backup that
file before doing any change. For further details,
see [VirtualBox Docs: 10.1.3. Global Configuration Data](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#vboxconfigdata-global).

Comment: This did not work, but I found the solution. Unfortunately, the HardDisk information is now located in each individual VM's .vbox file. Even though one deletes it in the config, it still will be listed here, and this is what is referenced by the GUI. While Vbox was not running, I deleted the appropriate lines and the associated snapshots and that solved the issue.

Comment: @user31883 From your question, I thought you've also deleted the VM from Virtual box.

Comment: Ahh I should have been more specific. You actually did help get me thinking and I looked for the HardDisk option elsewhere, so thank you.