# Windows 7 VM error VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND cmd

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, virtualbox, powershell

i have a windows 10 host and windows 7 guest, but every time i enter this command with or without the -partitions argument i get errors
for context, i'm using an elevated PowerShell and an elevated Command Prompt

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename C:\VirtualBoxDrives\drivename.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 -partitions 1 

(output)
VBoxManage.exe: error: VMDK: could not create new file 
'C:\VirtualBoxDrives\drivename.vmdk'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Error code VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND at F:\tinderbox\win- 
6.0\src\VBox\Storage\VMDK.cpp(3402) in function int __cdecl vmdkCreateRawImage(struct 
VMDKIMAGE *,struct VDISKRAW *const ,unsigned __int64)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Cannot create the raw disk VMDK: VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND
VBoxManage.exe: error: The raw disk vmdk file was not created
```

this is the drive structure

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online         1863 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    No Media           0 B      0 B
  Disk 3    No Media           0 B      0 B
  Disk 4    No Media           0 B      0 B
  Disk 5    No Media           0 B      0 B
  Disk 6    No Media           0 B      0 B

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     C   agbvaderWin  NTFS   Partition   1861 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 3     E                NTFS   Partition    916 GB  Healthy
  Volume 4     H   FACTORY_IMA  NTFS   Partition     14 GB  Healthy
  Volume 5     F                       Removable       0 B  No Media
  Volume 6     G                       Removable       0 B  No Media
  Volume 7     I                       Removable       0 B  No Media
  Volume 8     J                       Removable       0 B  No Media
  Volume 9     K                       Removable       0 B  No Media
```

i don't know what to do... it seems just fine, but it doesn't work. it is a file likely related to creating virtual hard dives like this, not a deleted virtual drive. it's a real drive named F:\ that is no longer in my pc which i no longer have and i have no idea how files were installed to it from virtualbox. i've even tried a reinstall which didn't work. i need to add something. that other removable drive F: is unrelated entirely and came from an sd card reader that i have plugged in. the installation of virtualbox was back when there was an external drive in it's place.

also, how do i allow a vm to use my real graphics card?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clean up intentionally deleted Virtualbox drives manually](https://superuser.com/questions/1417538/clean-up-intentionally-deleted-virtualbox-drives-manually)